# ImportError: No module named OpenGL.GL

Tags: python, opengl

I'm trying to run NeHe's tutorial [here](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/adding_colour/13003/) using Python 2.7.3, but It's throwing the error `ImportError: No module named OpenGL.GL`

So how do I fix that? This is the code:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
```

Comment: Silly question. Did you install PyOpenGL? [Using OpenGL in Python](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/ctypes/using.html)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Do you have PyOpenGL installed correctly?  If you are having n00bie issues getting new modules set up correctly, I recommend installing [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/).  Once you have setuptools installed, you will find a program in your python27/Scripts directory called "easy_install" that you can use to get packages installed correctly.

For instance on my windows setup, I use:

```
C:\Python27\scripts\easy_install pyopengl
```

to set up PyOpenGL on my system, and then your example case works fine.  I remember when I started using Python I had the same issues trying to get a working PyOpenGL set up correctly so I could run the NeHe code, and all of my issues went away when I learned about easy_install

On Linux:

```
sudo easy_install pyopengl
```

As well as:

```
sudo apt-get install python python-numpy python-opengl python-qt4 python-qt4-gl
```

Comment: with pip: `/path/to/python -m pip install pyopengl`

Comment: What is the advantage of using SetupTools over just a PIP Install?

Answer (score 24):

basically you need to install opengl but the library in python is called `pyopengl` not `opengl` you can use the pip install command inside anaconda prompt which can be done by the following command:

```
pip install pyopengl
```

Answer (score 10):

anaconda is a great python package manager,if you have anaconda,just:

```
conda install pyopengl
```

Answer (score 7):

It means you don"t have that module,,

Install it by using any python packet manager.

For LINUX
  just execute either one of things down below

Debian based

***for python v3.x***

```
apt-get install python3-opengl
```

***this is for python v2.x***

```
apt-get install python-opengl
```

***with easy_install***

```
easy_install pyopengl
```

***with conda pakage manager***

```
conda install pyopengl
```

***by python itself***

```
python -m pip install pyopengl
```

***for WINDOWS:***

run the `easy_installer` in `command prompt` located in `root directory` of `python`, where u have installed

ex:  `D:\Python36\scripts\easy_install pyopengl`

***For apple computer***

```
brew install pyopengl
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using openSUSE Linux Tumbleweed and had the same error (yes I have installed python3-opengl [via zypper package manager] and PyOpenGL [via pip]).

Solved the problem by using python3 explicitly to run command, because it seems that the installation is done for the newes version of python. The normal python command runs older python 2.

In short:

```
python opengl_test.py    # Does NOT work
python3 opengl_test.py   # Works
```

Answer (score -2):

Edit:found the answer: 
from the upper menu go to File >> Settings >> Project: projectname
from there select the suitable interpreter path.

Note: somehow by default it was set to "venv" folder path which my PyOpenGL is not installed. through the dropdown, I selected the "python" folder.

Comment: In case someone stumbles across this and is wondering why it got downvotes, this is curving best practices in suggesting that OP should not be using a virtual environment and instead be using their global environment, something that is not recommended in almost all cases when working with Python. What this responder should have done was install the corresponding packages in their virtual environment for the project ("venv" folder path) and leave the interpreter path as-is.